# How do I access the current verbs of an file in c#?

Tags: .net, windows, c#-4.0

I have a requirement in my project where I need to check the verbs of certain files(for eg. open,edit,pin to taskBar). Note that I do not need all the verbs associated with the files rather I need only the current verbs. For example if a file in already pinned to taskbar "unpin from taskbar" should be one of the current verbs.I tried using ProcessStartInfo for the above purpose by following https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb(v=vs.110).aspx.
Still it's not giving me all the verbs.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Those verbs were removed in Win10.  Feature, not a bug.